# Cannot connect bluetooth remote control to SBC running linux

Tags: bluetooth, embedded-linux, hci, nanopi

I am running a buildroot-generated linux image (kernel 4.11.2) on a nanopi NEO air board, and I struggle to connect to my ruwido remote control.
I can see it when I scan the devices using hcitool :

```
# hcitool lescan
LE Scan ...
<snip>
5C:F8:21:85:8E:67 ruwido
<snip>
```

But I cannot get a connection (it acts like the remote is not here) :

```
# hcitool cc 5C:F8:21:85:8E:67
Can't create connection: Input/output error
```

The only thing I can do is get some information about it :

```
# hcitool leinfo 5C:F8:21:85:8E:67
Requesting information ...
        Handle: 64 (0x0040)
        LMP Version: 4.0 (0x6) LMP Subversion: 0x140
        Manufacturer: Texas Instruments Inc. (13)
        Features: 0x01 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00
```

I also cannot use bluetoothctl since it doesn't detect my interface, even though it's initialized, bluetoothd is running and the modules are loaded :

```
# lsmod
Module                  Size  Used by
bnep                   20480  2
hci_uart               61440  1
btbcm                  16384  1 hci_uart
btqca                  16384  1 hci_uart
btintel                16384  1 hci_uart
bluetooth             348160  12 hci_uart,btintel,btqca,bnep,btbcm
brcmfmac              245760  0
brcmutil               16384  1 brcmfmac
sunxi_cir              16384  0
# ps -e | grep bluetooth
  553 root     /usr/sbin/bluetoothd
  731 root     grep bluetooth
# sudo hciconfig -a
hci0:   Type: Primary  Bus: UART
        BD Address: F7:93:3E:74:CF:62  ACL MTU: 1021:8  SCO MTU: 64:1
        UP RUNNING 
        RX bytes:12593 acl:7 sco:0 events:292 errors:0
        TX bytes:2050 acl:4 sco:0 commands:155 errors:0
        Features: 0xbf 0xfe 0xcf 0xfe 0xdb 0xff 0x7b 0x87
        Packet type: DM1 DM3 DM5 DH1 DH3 DH5 HV1 HV2 HV3 
        Link policy: RSWITCH SNIFF 
        Link mode: SLAVE ACCEPT 
        Name: 'NanoPi-NEO-Air'
        Class: 0x000000
        Service Classes: Unspecified
        Device Class: Miscellaneous, 
        HCI Version: 4.1 (0x7)  Revision: 0x0
        LMP Version: 4.1 (0x7)  Subversion: 0x2209
        Manufacturer: Broadcom Corporation (15)

# bluetoothctl 
Agent registered
[bluetooth]# power on
No default controller available
```

My question is, how do I get the remote paired and connected to the board ? It doesn't matter if it's through hcitool, bluetoothctl or another tool.

## Update

Thanks to [Prabhakar Lad's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3336541/prabhakar-lad) comment, bluetoothctl is now detecting the interface, <strike>however the problem still remains</strike> and the problem seems to have narrowed :

```
# rfkill unblock all
# hciconfig hci0 up
# hciconfig -a
hci0:   Type: Primary  Bus: UART
        BD Address: AA:AA:AA:AA:AA:AA  ACL MTU: 1021:8  SCO MTU: 64:1
        UP RUNNING PSCAN 
        RX bytes:1930 acl:0 sco:0 events:101 errors:0
        TX bytes:1587 acl:0 sco:0 commands:103 errors:0
        Features: 0xbf 0xfe 0xcf 0xfe 0xdb 0xff 0x7b 0x87
        Packet type: DM1 DM3 DM5 DH1 DH3 DH5 HV1 HV2 HV3 
        Link policy: RSWITCH SNIFF 
        Link mode: SLAVE ACCEPT 
        Name: 'BlueZ 5.47'
        Class: 0x000000
        Service Classes: Unspecified
        Device Class: Miscellaneous, 
        HCI Version: 4.1 (0x7)  Revision: 0x0
        LMP Version: 4.1 (0x7)  Subversion: 0x2209
        Manufacturer: Broadcom Corporation (15)

# bluetoothctl
[NEW] Controller F7:93:3E:74:CF:62 BlueZ 5.47 [default]
[NEW] Device 5C:F8:21:85:8E:67 ruwido
Agent registered
[bluetooth]# agent on
Agent is already registered
[bluetooth]# power on
Changing power on succeeded
[bluetooth]# scan on
Discovery started
[CHG] Controller F7:93:3E:74:CF:62 Discovering: yes
<snip>
[NEW] Device 5C:F8:21:85:8E:67 ruwido
<snip>
[bluetooth]# scan off
<snip>
[CHG] Device 5C:F8:21:85:8E:67 RSSI is nil
<snip>
[CHG] Controller F7:93:3E:74:CF:62 Discovering: no
Discovery stopped
[bluetooth]# pair 5C:F8:21:85:8E:67
Attempting to pair with 5C:F8:21:85:8E:67
[CHG] Device 5C:F8:21:85:8E:67 Connected: yes
[ruwido]# [  501.424858] Bluetooth: hci0 unexpected SMP command 0x0b from 5c:f8:21:85:8e:67
[CHG] Device 5C:F8:21:85:8E:67 Connected: no
[bluetooth]# pair 5C:F8:21:85:8E:67
Attempting to pair with 5C:F8:21:85:8E:67
Failed to pair: org.bluez.Error.ConnectionAttemptFailed
```

The SMP error seems to be related to [bluetooth low-energy security](https://community.nxp.com/thread/332191), so am I supposed to use a different tool for pairing ?

### Additional information

I actually use the busybox init system with bluetooth init scripts I found in the manufacturer's image (which is [nanopi-neo-air_FriendlyCore-Xenial_4.11.2_20171113.img](http://www.mediafire.com/file/8xr37t22qv8qf3p/nanopi-neo-air_FriendlyCore-Xenial_4.11.2_20171113.img.zip)) and adapted so that they could be used with busybox init (the init system on the image is systemd/upstart).
So I have two files :

- [/etc/init.d/S35brcm_patchram_plus](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/34f505d93253ead3ba1dfa3b0121a7c1) : patches firmware (the card uses an AMPAK ap6212 bluetooth/wifi combo module)
- [/etc/init.d/S38bluetooth](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/a3080a74e7ad323936d905663b448ae9) : starts bluetoothd

I use bluez 5.47 with the following options in buildroot 2017.08.1 :

```
BR2_PACKAGE_BLUEZ_TOOLS=y
# BR2_PACKAGE_BLUEZ_UTILS is not set
BR2_PACKAGE_BLUEZ5_UTILS=y
BR2_PACKAGE_BLUEZ5_UTILS_OBEX=y
BR2_PACKAGE_BLUEZ5_UTILS_CLIENT=y
BR2_PACKAGE_BLUEZ5_UTILS_DEPRECATED=y
# BR2_PACKAGE_BLUEZ5_UTILS_EXPERIMENTAL is not set
# BR2_PACKAGE_BLUEZ5_PLUGINS_HEALTH is not set
# BR2_PACKAGE_BLUEZ5_PLUGINS_MIDI is not set
# BR2_PACKAGE_BLUEZ5_PLUGINS_NFC is not set
# BR2_PACKAGE_BLUEZ5_PLUGINS_SAP is not set
BR2_PACKAGE_BLUEZ5_UTILS_TEST=y
# BR2_PACKAGE_BLUEZ5_UTILS_GATTTOOL is not set
```

Comment: can you try 'rfkill unblock all' then followed by restarting the service for bluetooth 'systemctl restart bluetooth' and then try bluetoothctl tool. BTW which version of bluez are you using ? Fyi C code to pair [1]
http://prabhakarlad.blogspot.co.uk/2017/09/bluez5-pairing-devices-tricks.html

Comment: Many thanks for your reply, bluetoothctl is working now, however the remote is not connecting. I've updated my post with the new status.

Answer (score 0):

You didnt go through my complete [post](http://prabhakarlad.blogspot.co.uk/2017/09/bluez5-pairing-devices-tricks.html), you need to perform following
 steps after you have done with rfkill and service restart:

a] `bluetoothctl`

```
Start the tool, this should detect the controller
```

b] `[bluetooth]# agent on`

```
Turn on the pairing agent
```

c] `[bluetooth]# scan on`

```
Let bluez detect your device, look in my post it should print you baddr (5C:F8:21:85:8E:67)
```

d] `[bluetooth]# scan off`

```
Turn off scanning once your device is discovered
```

e] [bluetooth]# pair 5C:F8:21:85:8E:67

```
Now pair to the device
```

It should now be paired.
Note: you cannot pair a device until the bluez has scanned it.

Comment: Thanks again, I didn't think the scanning was mandatory. The post has been updated with the current status. It actually looks like a security issue.

Comment: Apply this patch https://bugzilla.kernel.org/attachment.cgi?id=186691&action=edit and see if that fixes your problem!

Comment: It is already applied in the kernel I use so it didn't change the problem. I did manage to read characteristics from the remote using gatttool, so I wonder about using this to read the values of the pressed keys.

Comment: You mean gatttool is able to connect ? also you might want to try https://github.com/sandeepmistry/noble this will make life easier!

Comment: Yes, I can connect to the remote using gatttool. Thanks for the suggestion, but unfortunately I cannot use nodeJS in the project I'm working on.